# Como traduzir "superscript" e "subscript symbol"?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

Normalmente, quando se usam notações (por exemplo na Física ou Matemática), em que se tem um símbolo (de menor tamanho) posicionado ligeiramente acima de um outro símbolo, diz-se em inglês que o primeiro se encontra em "superscript" relativamente ao segundo.

Por outro lado, caso se coloque um símbolo ligeiramente abaixo de um outro, diz-se que o primeiro se encontra em "subscript" relativamente ao segundo.

Quais são as traduções correctas de "superscript" e "subscript" para o português? Poderiam ser por exemplo, "sobrescrito" e "subscrito", respectivamente?

Comment: superscript and subscript **numbers**, you should say....

Comment: They go beyond just numbers. They could be numbers, letters, special characters and possibly others

Comment: **A superscript is the little number** that is sometimes placed up and to the right of other numbers. The context of its use determines what the superscript's meaning is. Here are some examples of superscripts as used in math. https://study.com/academy/lesson/superscript-in-math-definition-example-quiz.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim, "sobrescrito" e "subscrito" são corretos, como registra, e.g., o [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/sobrescrito):

> 5. Que está escrito acima da linha ou do alinhamento (ex.: em 10⁶ há um número sobrescrito).
>    Confrontar: subscrito.

Quando se trata de potenciação, naturalmente o símbolo sobrescrito é o "expoente".

E quando se tratam de índices (e.g., de tensores), então nos referimos a eles como "índices superiores" e "índices inferiores".